# I got this assignment about calculating miles per hour, but my runner program cant seem to locate my time variable

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MPHRunner
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

        out.print("Enter the distance :: ");
        int dist = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the hours :: ");
        int hrs = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the minutes :: ");
        int mins = keyboard.nextInt();

        MilesPerHour test = new MilesPerHour(dist, hrs, mins,time);
        test.calcMPH(dist,time);
        test.print();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, it tells me that it cannot locate the variable `time`. It should be found from the other class, included below...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MilesPerHour
{
    public int distance, hours, minutes;
    public double mph, time;

    public MilesPerHour()
    {
        setNums(0,0,0,0);
        mph=0.0;
    }

    public MilesPerHour(int dist, int hrs, int mins)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        out.println("enter distance");
        out.println("enter hours");
        out.println("enter minutes");
    }

    public void setNums(int dist, int hrs, int mins, double time)
    {
        distance = dist;
        hours = hrs;
        minutes = mins;
        time = ((hrs*60)+mins)/60;
    }

    public void calcMPH(int dist, double time)
    {
        mph = dist/time;
    }

    public void print(int mph, int dist, double time)
    {
        System.out.println("at "+mph+"MPH, you can go "+dist+" miles in "+time+"hours.");
    }
}
```

Any assistance with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If your *teacher* doesn't understand why your `main` method is broken, that's a really significant problem :( Where would you expect it to get the `time` variable from, and why? (Bear in mind that you're referring to it without any qualification.)

Comment: There's other problems with the code besides the time not working. `setNums(int dist, int hrs, int mins, double time)` this method doesn't set the time field properly.

Comment: Just like Jon Skeet is saying.... time isn't a "magical" variable you can use and your system doesn't know what "time" is. this is what's happening here

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

out.print("Enter the distance :: ");
int dist = keyboard.nextInt();

out.print("Enter the hours :: ");
int hrs = keyboard.nextInt();

out.print("Enter the minutes :: ");
int mins = keyboard.nextInt();
```

It doesn't matter about what goes on in the object. Here, you're declaring and defining `dist`, `hrs` and `mins`, then in the next line:

```
MilesPerHour test = new MilesPerHour(dist, hrs, mins,time);
```

This isn't going to compile because `time` has not been declared.

**Edit**

On closer inspection, I've noted that `time` is calculated from other fields. In that case, you don't need to specify it in the parameters because you don't need for it to be passed in. Change

```
public void setNums(int dist, int hrs, int mins, double time)
```

to

```
public void setNums(int dist, int hrs, int mins)
```

and remove it from the arguments list when you call the `setNums` method.

***NOTE***: If your teacher couldn't diagnose the compilation problems here, then I would certainly report them to your educational institution. This is something that a novice programmer should be able to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor MilesPerHour only has 3 parameters but you try to pass 4 parameters from your main class. Moreover the 4th parameter (time) is not even delcared.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't declared a time variable in your static main function.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a variable named 'time' as an argument to the constructor of your MilesPerHour object in your main method, but you have not declared/defined this variable anywhere. Presumably you want to add a line:

```
double time = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

...before the object constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your `time` variable.

```
out.print("Enter the time:: ");
double time = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

and you must add a constructor for `MilesPerHour` that takes the parameter time, like so:

```
public MilesPerHour(int dist, int hrs, int mins, double time){...}
```

however, you are actually calculating your time variable from the inputs `hrs` and `mins`
so all your constructor should do is call the `setNums` method.

```
    public MilesPerHour(int dist, int hrs, int mins, double time){
        setNums(dist, hrs, mins);
    }
```

I would advise you to change the `setNums` method slightly:

```
public void setNums(int dist, int hrs, int mins) //remove time variable
{
    distance = dist;
    hours = hrs;
    minutes = mins;
    this.time = ((hrs*60)+mins)/60; //we are talking about this specific instance of the class, so we do not need to pass in time as a parameter.
}
```